# How to use gojs brush pattern so that an image is repeated only at height and not in width

Tags: gojs

I use a rectangle shape, I want to fill it with an image, so that the image is repeating vertically, but stretching horizontally.

my code is:

```
 $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", {
                fill: $(go.Brush, "Pattern", { pattern: img }),
                stroke: null,
                width:x,
                height:34,
                position: new go.Point(0,14)
 })
```

Comment: Maybe I should stretch the picture laterally, but in fact I don't success.  I tried to set img.width and img.style.width, but  that didn't make any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjusting the size of the <img> element won't have any effect.  I think you need to actually stretch the image in the file so that it has the natural width that you want.  45 pixels in this case.

Comment: The width is dynamic so I can't change the file according to it. (I changed in the question)

Answer (score 0):

I use canvas, and in the load function, I changed the image-width to be like the wraped graphObject

```
     $(go.Shape, "Rectangle", {
                    fill: $(go.Brush, "Pattern", {
                        pattern: getPattern()
                    }),
                    stroke: null
                },
                    new go.Binding("width", "", () => {
                      ...;
                    }),
                    new go.Binding("height", "", (data) => {
                        return ...;
                    }),
                    new go.Binding("position", "", () => {
                        return new go.Point(..., ...);
                    }))
    
    ---
    
     function getPattern() {
            let width = cabinetWidth;
            var patternCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            patternCanvas.width = width;
            patternCanvas.height = 2;
            var pctx = patternCanvas.getContext('2d');
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = "../../../../assets/images/xxx.png";
            img.onload = function () {
                pctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, patternCanvas.width, patternCanvas.height);
            }
            return patternCanvas;

    }
```

Comment: This was going to be my next suggestion.  Does this work for you?